# Generate a pdf from powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext7

I'm trying to generate a PDF with powershell but I don't know how to proceed. I already tried to use Itext 7 but I don't know how to make it work.

When i try to install Itext7 on powershell i have this error message :

```
No match found for the specified search criteria and the itext7 package name. Use 
Get-PackageSource to display for all available registered package sources.
```

Could I have some help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of PowerShell dependencies can be problematic as they need to be of a ***known working group in time and 7.1.14 was touted as a light solution*** so see later TL;DR edits or others comments below, ***[Later EDIT for more recent heavier list of 7.2.# dependencies see answer by @paul-oneill ] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75280860/10802527)*** and run as Admin perhaps different to a normal user. So follow these steps carefully as some may downgrade your current settings.

MOST IMPORTANT use a project directory and watch that your prompt is located in that folder to ensure you are not running in the default PowerShell directory. I use a shortcut where the target directory is "blank/empty" thus defaults to the current working folder.

1st Check:-

```
project folder>[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
```

should return either Tls12 or Tls13 we need it to be 1.2 so keep a note if yours is set to Tls13 and run this line.

```
 [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

we may need to possibly change package provider so first check if nuget includes https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/:-

```
> Get-PackageSource

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
nuget.org                        NuGet            False      https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
PSGallery                        PowerShellGet    False      https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
```

If not you can add it as

```
Register-PackageSource nuget.org https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ -ProviderName NuGet
```

now you should be able to install the dlls as follows

```
Install-Package -Name "itext7" -ProviderName NuGet -RequiredVersion 7.1.14 -Destination . -SkipDependencies
Install-Package -Name Portable.BouncyCastle -ProviderName NuGet -RequiredVersion 1.8.9.0 -Destination . -SkipDependencies
Install-Package -Name Common.Logging -ProviderName NuGet -RequiredVersion 3.4.1.0 -Destination . -SkipDependencies
Install-Package -Name Common.Logging.Core -ProviderName NuGet -RequiredVersion 3.4.1.0 -Destination . -SkipDependencies
```

Double check your folder has the correct structure
[image]

Note the order and location of the script is critical for correct loading

```
    Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot ".\Common.Logging.Core.3.4.1\lib\net40\Common.Logging.Core.dll")
    Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot ".\Common.Logging.3.4.1\lib\net40\Common.Logging.dll")
    Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot ".\Portable.BouncyCastle.1.8.9\lib\net40\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll")
    Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot ".\itext7.7.1.14\lib\net40\itext.io.dll")
    Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot ".\itext7.7.1.14\lib\net40\itext.layout.dll")
    Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot ".\itext7.7.1.14\lib\net40\itext.kernel.dll")

    $pdfDocuFilename = (join-path $PSScriptRoot "My1st.pdf")
    $pdfWriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($pdfDocuFilename)
    $pdfdocument = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfWriter)
    $pdfdocument.AddNewPage()

    $pdfdocument.Close()
```

**This will produce an empty file but proves all is well,** and you can start running other examples such as the one suggested by S_G, so after the loading Add-Type block replace my blank example with

```
[string] $DEST = "HelloWorld.pdf"
$pdfWriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($DEST)
$pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfWriter)
$document = [iText.Layout.Document]::new($pdf)
$document.Add([iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph]::new("Hello World! from Powershell"))
$pdf.Close()
```

... Good Luck.

- **The versions above were for a fixed point in time** when user blogs had verified that 7.1 mixes worked without much conflict, the aim is to produce a group of standalone files working within **Net40** environment, but time moves on and you should ensure you are using a newer mix. **HOWEVER everything changed in 7.1.15** as a phenomenally greater list of dependencies is now required for Net 4.5 and now 4.6.1 although, packages/itext7/7.2.1 itself still works with
  packages/Portable.BouncyCastle/1.8.9 + and common logging is still 3.4.1

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This works perfectly. You have saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for a PowerShell Script which outputs a PDF with "Hello World!" written on it. It mirrors the functionality of iText 7 basic Hello World example. You can change it as per your requirement.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Common.Logging.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\itext.io.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\itext.layout.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\itext.kernel.dll"

[string] $DEST = "C:\files\HelloWorldPowerShell.pdf"
$pdfWriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($DEST)
$pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfWriter)
$document = [iText.Layout.Document]::new($pdf)
$document.Add([iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph]::new("Hello World!"))
$pdf.Close()
```

Comment: thank you but how can I install the indicated dll?

Comment: Please check this https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7

Run the following command from package manager to download iText 7 dll files
Install-Package itext7 -Version 7.2.1

Comment: I dont know how to use nuget with powershell, i never use it

Comment: i run the following command in powershell ?

Comment: when i run it in powershell i have an error "Could not find a parameter matching the name "Version"." @S_G

Comment: How can I install this package?

Comment: I finally managed to install itext however I don't have the DLL files specified in the code. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I found some good info here what DLLs need to be loaded via add-type ... https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/design/graphic/pdf/tools/iText/index

Through trial & error I found loading the below works for itext7 versions 7.2.0, 7.2.4 & 7.2.5.

```
   # DLL list - https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/
$dll_list = @(
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Common.Logging.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\itext.commons.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\itext.forms.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\itext.io.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\itext.kernel.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\itext.layout.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\System.Memory.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\System.ValueTuple.dll"
    "$my_ScriptDir\DLL_7.2.4\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
)

# Loop & load DLLs
foreach ($dll in $dll_list)
{
    Write-Host "Loading $dll" -ForegroundColor Green
    try { Add-Type -Path "$dll"} 
    catch { $dll.Exception.LoaderExceptions }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents but the above code does NOT work with Itext7 7.2.1 (after modifying for proper paths).
Wish I'd seen this post last week - wasted most of several days pulling hair out over 7.2.1 not behaving itself. :(